# How to copy list item between two list in different site but one server in sharepoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I have two list
List A and list B
I want to copy item from list A to list B when the column "Move" in list A is yes
List A and list B is in different site but same server
I am using sharepoint 2010

Answer (score 0):

You should think about event receiver and associate it to List A on `ItemAdded` and `ItemUpdated` to check if the value of column "Move" is yes then create a new listitem in List B then delete the listitem in List A

Edit: you can achieve that by using SharePoint Object Model to write a Feature with Event Receiver in C# or VB and deploy it to the server

Comment: do you mean using workflow in sharepoint designer, i have try it, but my problem is how to copy item to list B because list B is in another site
thank's for your help